# Incorrect Total Pages in SSRS (2014) Report for PDF

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on the Invoice Report(SSRS 2014) which is a huge report consist of multiple sub-reports for notes and Terms and conditions. I have used Standard Global Variable to show the page numbers as :

`Globals!PageNumber & "  of  " & Globals!TotalPages`

But, it is showing incorrect total pages if the PDF has 9 pages only it will show in the total pages textbox as 10 (1 of 10). The last page of the PDF shows 9 f 10 pages, there is no page after the 9th page.
No blank spaces as well. The `Globals!TotalPages` experesion
causing the problem. This issue is not coming frequently it is coming for only 2 or 3 invoices among 50. Anyone has any idea to get rid of this issue?

Comment: Do you have the same PageSize and InteractiveSize

Comment: @niktrs - Yes, both  have same size . Width - 8.5in and Height - 11in

Comment: I ran into this issue using subreports within subreports. The fix I had to do is to place subreports in the same parent report.

Comment: @reas - Yeah. All my Subreports are in the parent report only.